# Github: How can I check number of code lines in a Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In my Ruby on Rails project, I am trying to install a github action to verify the number of code lines and for example limit it to 200 lines (deltas), to avoid create big pull requests.

Could someone mend any configuration or github action to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout pr-branch
git diff --stat master HEAD^
```